# How to pass Blitz++ subarray as an input/output parameter of a procedure

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, procedure, blitz++

I have an FFT procedure `fftconvx` taking two tensors `Ttnsr` and `S` as input parameters and producing a result into another tensor `G`. All tensors are defined as Blitz++ arrays `Array<complex<double>, N>`, where `N` is the rank of the array. The procedure `fftconvx` has to be called multiple times inside of a double loop.

Ideally I would like to pass subarrays `Stnsr(ri,rj,rk,0)` or `Stnsr(ri,rj,rk,1)` and receive the result into subarrays `Gtnsr(t,p,ri,rj,rk,0)` or `Gtnsr(t,p,ri,rj,rk,1)` as follows:

```
fftconvx( Gtnsr(t,p,ri,rj,rk,0), Ttnsr, Stnsr(ri,rj,rk,0) );
```

Variables `ri,rj,rk` are Blitz++ array ranges. Unfortunately this does not work and results in the following compilation error:

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 
‘blitz::Array<std::complex<double>, 3>&’ from an rvalue of type 
‘blitz::SliceInfo<std::complex<double>, int, int, blitz::Range, blitz::Range, 
 blitz::Range, int, blitz::nilArraySection, blitz::nilArraySection, 
 blitz::nilArraySection, blitz::nilArraySection, blitz::nilArraySection>::T_slice
{aka blitz::Array<std::complex<double>, 3>}’

fftconvx(Gtnsr(t,p,ri,rj,rk,0), Ttnsr, Stnsr(ri,rj,rk,0));
```

Signature of the `fftconvx` is:

```
void fftconvx(Array<complex<double>, 3> &c,
              Array<complex<double>, 3> x2,
              Array<complex<double>, 3> x1,
              ...);
```

There more arrays and variables passed as input parameters, but I omit them for brevity.

So far I have come up with the solution based on temporary arrays `S` and `G`:

```
S(ri,rj,rk) = Stnsr(ri,rj,rk,0);

fftconvx(G, Ttnsr, S);

Gtnsr(t,p,ri,rj,rk,0) = G(ri,rj,rk);
```

I believe there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: How is fftconvx declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing Blitz++ I offer this possible solution.

It looks like Gtnsr is a SliceInfo and not a Array, but that is has a operator Array.

So changing the `fftconvx` into

```
template<class SliceOrArray>
void fftconvx(SliceOrArray &c,
              const Array<complex<double>, 3> x2,
              const Array<complex<double>, 3> x1,
              ...);
```

might work if the operations in fftconvx allows the use of the slice.

If Blitz++ is opdated to C++11 the following might work as well.

```
G fftconvx(   const Array<complex<double>, 3> x2,
              const Array<complex<double>, 3> x1,
              ...) {
    G c;
    ...
    return c; // C++11 NRVO
};
```

and then calling

```
Gtnsr(t,p,ri,rj,rk,0) = fftconvx( ... );
```

Comment: Thank you for the proposal. First option results in the following error: `error: in passing argument 1 of ‘void ftconvx(SliceOrArray&, blitz::Array<std::complex<double>, 3>, blitz::Array<std::complex<double>, 3>, blitz::Array<std::complex<double>, 3>, blitz::Array<std::complex<double>, 3>, blitz::Array<std::complex<double>, 3>, blitz::Array<std::complex<double>, 3>, fftw_plan, fftw_plan, int, int, int, blitz::Range, blitz::Range, blitz::Range) [with SliceOrArray = blitz::Array<std::complex<double>, 3>; fftw_plan = fftw_plan_s*]’`.

Comment: Second option has worked. The function should be defined as `Array<complex<double>, 3> fftconvx(Array<complex<double>, 3> x2, Array<complex<double>, 3> x1, ...)` and the return Blitz++ array should be defined at the end of `fftconvx` as `Array<complex<double>, 3> c( x3t(ri,rj,rk) / (8.0*mi*mj*mk) ); return c;` This also solved the problem of passing a subarray `Stnsr(ri,rj,rk,0)` to `fftconvx` directly.